# Пользовательское поле с типом Дата/Время не отображается в календаре сделоки

Tags: битрикс

Календарь сделок в Битрикс24 можно настроить так, чтобы отображались выбранные даты.
Мануал утверждает, что "Для отображения доступны поля Дата создания для Лидов, Дата создания и Дата завершения для Сделок, а также все пользовательские поля с типом Дата/Время и Бронирование ресурсов." https://helpdesk.bitrix24.ru/open/7481073/
Я ввел для Сделок пользовательское поле с типом Дата/Время, но отображение в календаре по этому полю настроить нельзя, календарь его не видит. Включены реквизиты поля: Обязательное, Показывать в фильтре, показывать в списке